# how to insert many records

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, android-sqlite

When I insert more than 500 records into sqlite database, an error "too many terms in compound `SELECT`" occurs. I have read the details about [sqlite limit](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)

Now I want to insert more than 1000 (say 2000 products) records into the database. Can anyone suggest, how to write query to insert more than 1000 records.

Here is the insert query I have used:

```
INSERT INTO Product 
    SELECT 
       '4886229673836544' AS productId, 
       'Pen1' AS productName, 
       '10' As sellingPrice 
    UNION SELECT 
       '4780676557570048', 
       'Pen2', '10'........... 
    UNION SELECT 
       '4562973255270400', 
       'Pen1000', 
       '10'
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a parameterized query like the following:

```
INSERT INTO Products
VALUES (@ProductId, @ProductName, @SellingPrice)
```

And use it in the following way (pseudocode):

```
create statement
add parameter definitions to parameter collection
prepare statement
start transaction
for each row you want to insert
   set parameter values
   execute statement

commit transaction
```

Comment: @lopez: why you are using @? can explain a bit about this.                                  function insertRecord (query) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
          if (query) {
            tx.executeSql(query, [], function () {
              console.log('insert successful');
              deferred.resolve();
            });
          } else {
            deferred.resolve();
          }
        });
        return deferred.promise;
      };

Comment: @YogeshN You tagged the question "android-sqlite". Why are you showing JavaScript code?

Comment: @cl but my issue was in sqlite. i am using cordova to run as android app, So i have added android-sqlite tag.

Comment: @Yogesh. Parameter names in SQLite can start with @ or with :

Comment: @Yogesh. Actually you can use more prefixes as documented here: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam